# pass a column value to ssis variable

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a job that I want to run that passes a variable to an ssis package. The variable is a filename but the filename changes daily. I have an access front end that the user enters the filename into. The access program runs a stored procedure which writes the filename to a temp table and then runs the job. I would like the job to query that table for the filename and pass it along to my package variable.

I can get the job to work using a static filename. On the set values tab I used the property path \Package.Variables[User::FileName] and the value \myserver......\filename.txt. But I don't know how to replace that filename with the results of the query

Thanks in advance.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an Execute SQL Task in my package that assigns the value in the temp table to my package variable.

Answer (score 0):

I may have spoke too soon. The data source saved in my job step was still an value in my package. I had removed the value but didn't re-import the package to SQL. Now that I did that it is not importing anything at all.